Use jQuery to trigger SVG which has animate tag defined
I have a SVG animation:


html, body {
  background: #000;
}

.hb {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
<svg class="hb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width=".6" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke-linecap="round" style="cursor: pointer">
  <path d="M2,3L3.5,3L5,3M2,5L8,5M5,7L6.5,7L8,7">
    <animate dur="0.2s" attributeName="d" values="M2,3L3.5,3L5,3M2,5L8,5M2,7L5,7L8,7;M3,3L4,4L5,5M3,7L7,3M5,5L6,6L7,7" fill="freeze" begin="start.begin" />
    <animate dur="0.2s" attributeName="d" values="M3,3L4,4L5,5M3,7L7,3M5,5L6,6L7,7;M2,3L3.5,3L5,3M2,5L8,5M5,7L6.5,7L8,7" fill="freeze" begin="reverse.begin" />
  </path>
  <rect width="10" height="10" stroke="none">
    <animate dur="2s" id="reverse" attributeName="width" begin="click" />
  </rect>
  <rect width="10" height="10" stroke="none">
    <animate dur="0.001s" id="start" attributeName="width" values="10;0" fill="freeze" begin="click" />
    <animate dur="0.001s" attributeName="width" values="0;10" fill="freeze" begin="reverse.begin" />
  </rect>
</svg>



The animation works fine when interacting with mouse clicks. However, I want to use jQuery to trigger the animation with id="reverse". How can I do so?
My idea is: that when I first click the SVG icon, it starts to play a 0.2s animation and then shows the menu DIV. After the menu DIV's close button (#btn_menu_close) is clicked, the reverse SVG animation is played to change the SVG icon back to the original state.
My jQuery code (I am not using $ symbol as I am using it in WordPress):
jQuery('.hb').click(function() {
    function showMenu() {
        jQuery('.body-menu').fadeIn();
    }
    setTimeout(showMenu, 200);
});
jQuery('#btn_menu_close').click(function() {
    jQuery('.body-menu').fadeOut();
    // WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE to trigger the reverse animation?
});


document.querySelector("#reverse").beginElement() ?

It works! but is there a jQuery version? thanks.

Why the jQuery overhead if you now know the native JavaScript syntax, it will only cost more CPU cycles.,

well, jQuery is already loaded, and I don't want to mix jQuery codes with native JS codes.

Most jquery scripts "mix" native JS code with jquery specific methods (under the hood its still JS). The accepted answer actually converts the jquery selection to a native element - which is probably your only chance to get it working since JQ doesn't have specific methods to control/manipulate SVGs (at least in the past it had quite a few limitations with regards to SVG handling).

You can use $("#reverse")[0].beginElement(); to achieve your goal
Working snippet:


$("#reverse")[0].beginElement();
html, body {
  background: #000;
}

.hb {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="hb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" stroke="#eee" stroke-width=".6" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke-linecap="round" style="cursor: pointer">
  <path d="M2,3L3.5,3L5,3M2,5L8,5M5,7L6.5,7L8,7">
    <animate dur="0.2s" attributeName="d" values="M2,3L3.5,3L5,3M2,5L8,5M2,7L5,7L8,7;M3,3L4,4L5,5M3,7L7,3M5,5L6,6L7,7" fill="freeze" begin="start.begin" />
    <animate dur="0.2s" attributeName="d" values="M3,3L4,4L5,5M3,7L7,3M5,5L6,6L7,7;M2,3L3.5,3L5,3M2,5L8,5M5,7L6.5,7L8,7" fill="freeze" begin="reverse.begin" />
  </path>
  <rect width="10" height="10" stroke="none">
    <animate dur="2s" id="reverse" attributeName="width" begin="click" />
  </rect>
  <rect width="10" height="10" stroke="none">
    <animate dur="0.001s" id="start" attributeName="width" values="10;0" fill="freeze" begin="click" />
    <animate dur="0.001s" attributeName="width" values="0;10" fill="freeze" begin="reverse.begin" />
  </rect>
</svg>



